# R: Dividing certain cells in one dataframe by certain cells in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to divide certain cells in one dataframe by certain cells in another dataframe.

Dataframe1 -- The column names in the dataset are: Compound_Number, Compound_Concentration, Time, Technical_Replicate, and Colony_Count. In total, there are 12 compounds, 3 concentrations, 3 time points, and 6 technical replicates.

Dataframe2 -- The column names are Compound_Number, Technical_Replicate, Time, and Replicate_Mean. In total, there are 12 compounds, 3 time points, and 1 replicate mean.

I need to divide the Colony_Count in Dataframe1 by the Replicate_Mean in Dataframe2 -- but I need to make sure that the division occurs in a paired-fashion (e.g., the compound number must be the same, as well as the time and technical replicate).

I know that I can do all of this by hand...

```
#Dataframe1 (corpus)
C1_T1_TR1 <- corpus[ which(corpus$Compound_Number==1 & corpus$Technical_Replicate==1 & corpus$Time==1),]

#Dataframe2 (normalizing_means)
NC1_T1_TR1 <- normalizing_means[ which(normalizing_means$Compound_Number==1 & normalizing_means$Time==1 & normalizing_means$Technical_Replicate==1),]$Replicate_Mean
```

Then I can do...

```
C1_T1_TR1$Colony_Count/N1_T1
```

However, that means writing out those lines multiple times in order to catch all the compounds, replicates, and times -- and then merging the results from all those selections and operations back into a single dataframe. This is cumbersome and I am certain there is a better R way of doing it. I did see this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150534/divide-multiple-columns-of-one-data-frame-by-row-names-value-of-another-datafram,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150534/divide-multiple-columns-of-one-data-frame-by-row-names-value-of-another-datafram) but it is not quite what I need -- any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is a bit of data.

Dataframe1

```
Compound_Number Compound_Concentration  Time    Technical_Replicate Colony_Count
1   0.1 mM  5   4   46000000 #This is the example line
1   0.05 mM 5   4   109000000
1   0.02 mM 5   4   220000000
1   0.1 mM  25  4   30000
1   0.05 mM 25  4   16000000
1   0.02 mM 25  4   340000000
1   0.1 mM  1   1   5000000
1   0.05 mM 1   1   220000000
1   0.02 mM 1   1   210000000
1   0.1 mM  5   1   9000000
1   0.05 mM 5   1   70000000
1   0.02 mM 5   1   57000000
1   0.1 mM  5   2   560000
1   0.05 mM 5   2   34000000
1   0.02 mM 5   2   300000000
1   0.1 mM  25  2   10000
2   0.05 mM 1   3   120000000
2   0.02 mM 1   3   210000000
2   0.1 mM  5   3   280000000
2   0.05 mM 5   3   240000000
2   0.02 mM 5   3   80000000
2   0.1 mM  25  3   110000000
2   0.05 mM 25  3   250000000
2   0.02 mM 25  3   350000000
2   0.1 mM  1   4   290000000
2   0.05 mM 1   4   340000000
2   0.05 mM 1   1   300000000
2   0.02 mM 1   1   110000000
2   0.1 mM  5   1   510000000
2   0.05 mM 5   1   420000000
```

Dataframe2

```
Compound_Number Technical_Replicate Time    Replicate_Mean
1   1   1   288000000
1   1   5   232000000
1   1   25  230000000
1   2   1   351666666.666667
1   2   5   320000000
1   2   25  291666666.666667
1   3   1   570000000
1   3   5   493333333.333333
1   3   25  701666666.666667
1   4   1   425000000
1   4   5   630000000 #This is the example line
1   4   25  380000000
1   5   1   473333333.333333
1   5   5   463333333.333333
1   5   25  433333333.333333
1   6   1   478333333.333333
1   6   5   453333333.333333
1   6   25  520000000
2   1   1   391666666.666667
2   1   5   356666666.666667
2   1   25  373333333.333333
2   2   1   445000000
2   2   5   423333333.333333
2   2   25  353333333.333333
2   3   1   248333333.333333
2   3   5   281666666.666667
2   3   25  151666666.666667
2   4   1   325000000
2   4   5   360000000
2   4   25  420000000
2   5   1   156666666.666667
2   5   5   298333333.333333
2   5   25  338333333.333333
2   6   1   313333333.333333
2   6   5   318333333.333333
2   6   25  276666666.666667
```

For clarity this is an example row from Dataframe1:

```
Compound_Number  Compound_Concentration Time    Technical_Replicate Colony_Count
1   0.1 mM  5   4   46000000
```

I need to find the corresponding row in Dataframe2.

```
Compound_Number Technical_Replicate Time    Replicate_Mean
1   4   5   630000000
```

And I would like to divide 46000000 by 630000000.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just merge the dataframes on those three columns...? Then divide.

Comment: @sirallen -- OF COURSE!!! Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot take credit for this (although I hope I would have gotten there eventually).

```
NEW_DF <- merge(corpus, normalizing_means)
```

Then I can easily divide one column by another.

Thank you to @sirallen.